# how do I run run junit on remote postgresql docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, junit, testcontainers

I'm trying to run juinit on a remote postgresql docker.
I tried to use testcontainers.org but I can't get the configuration to work
I keep getting timeout exception
Does testcontainers support such setup? if so is there an example for that?

Thanks

Comment: could you please explain what "remote postgresql docker" is?

Comment: I would like to run a junit that before the test starts a postgresql docker on a remote linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have your Docker configured correctly, it should work out of the box without any additional configuration.
Just make sure that your environment variables point to the remote Docker daemon.

Comment: Thanks!. which enviroment variables should I configure?

Comment: I've succeeded to connect the problem was that my Linux docker daemon wasn't configured correctly